# Are all international wire transfers from a financial institution in France to a financial institution in the US SWIFT transfers?

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, wire-transfer, france, swift

I wonder whether all international wire transfers from a financial institution in France to a financial institution in the US are SWIFT transfers. Are can there be non-SWIFT transfers?

Comment: You'll have to ask the specific bank if they accept transfers in some other ways. Most likely they won't.

Comment: @littleadv what are the other possible ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are all international wire transfers from a financial institution in France to a financial institution in the US SWIFT transfers?

No.

Reddit user https://www.reddit.com/user/DeluxeXL [mentions](https://redd.it/10tvqbd) that international wire transfers from a financial institution in France to a financial institution in the US may use CHIPS instead of SWIFT, but only if the financial institutions are members of CHIPS:

> There are only 3 big wire transfer systems in the US: FedWire, SWIFT, and CHIPS. ([source 1](https://www.hgexperts.com/expert-witness-articles/decoding-swift-fedwire-and-chips-wire-transfer-messages-for-banking-funds-transfer-litigation-35874), [source 2](https://www.fincen.gov/sites/default/files/shared/Appendix_D.pdf)). (ACH, RTP, and FedNow are not wire transfers.)
>
> According to Wikipedia, [some banks in France are members of CHIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clearing_House_Interbank_Payments_System).
>
> So, if both the French bank and the US bank are members of CHIPS, they can do CHIPS wire transfer. Likewise, if they are both members of SWIFT, they can do SWIFT wire transfer.

https://tipalti.com/swift-payments/ mentions that SWIFT is the most commonly used:

> Although there are other real-time message services like Ripple, Fedwire, and Clearing House Interbank Payments Systems (CHIPS), SWIFT continues to retain a dominant position in capital markets. T